# I'm not able leave space between Account Settings in the below code , if i try I'm getting error React -Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = new createDrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard:{
    screen: InnerStackNavigator,
  }, 
  Account Settings:{
   screen: Dashboard
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way. Instead of `Account Settings` (with a space) go with `AccountSettings`
There's no explanation to it. This is just how you should practice.

Comment: then how to get Account Settings space in Navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

You need to place quotes around Account Settings, so it looks like the following:

```
"Account Settings": {
```

With JavaScript objects, the only time you can go without quotes on a key is if the key has no spaces.

Comment: how to style and position the elements in the navigation drawer in react native?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are trying to create an object and name of the object not allow any space, If you want to separate two words you can use '_' instead e.g Account_Settings.

vote up the answers that helped you the most!